# MySQL using "-" as different

Tags: mysql, undefined-behavior

It's not really a question, I already found out the answer the hard way.
The problem is with the following query.

```
delete from <table> where id - 145;
```

**Having minus** instead of **equals** was clearly **a typo**. The database's autocommit was turned on and I ended up deleting all the entries in the table except those with the id = 145. So the **minus over there acted as a "not equal" operator.**

I searched for similar situations and looked for this operator in the MySQL docs and I couldn't find anything.

**Is this supposed to happen this way? Is it normal or a MySQL bug?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delete from <table> where id - 145;
```

will work fine if `id` is `146` as `146-145=1` and mysql return true for 1 and false for 0;

Hope this solve your doubt.

Comment: This means that it ran
    `delete from <table> where true;`
and thus, deleting all the values. Why the entry with id=145 wasn't deleted?

Comment: Because 145-145=0 and 0 is FALSE

Comment: Oooh, yes. It makes sense now. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @AndreiPopescu i think ,you got answer by previous comment?

Answer (score 3):

This is perfectly as expected.

Consider the following queries:

```
delete from <table>;
delete from <table> where true;
delete from <table> where 1;
```

If you follow these, you can understand that any number not 0 is considered truthy. And 0 is considered falsy. So also:

```
delete from <table> where 3;
delete from <table> where 50;
delete from <table> where -1;
```

All these queries will delete everything in the table.

Now in your query, you do did `id - 145`. This will return a non-zero for every row, except for the row with id 145, simply because 145 - 145 = 0.

That is why everything got deleted except the row with id 145.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal, sort of. `id - 145` evaluates to nonzero when id is not 145 and nonzero evaluates to true in a boolean context like the where clause.

Answer (score 2):

> the minus over there acted as a "not equal" operator.

More or less. It doesn't work the same for strings.

The content of the `WHERE` clause is a condition. As the [documentation of `DELETE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) explains:

> `where_condition` is an expression that evaluates to true for each row to be deleted. It is specified as described in [Section 13.2.9, "`SELECT` Syntax"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

The linked page says:

> In the `WHERE` expression, you can use any of the functions and operators that MySQL supports, except for aggregate (summary) functions. See [Section 9.5, "Expression Syntax"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html), and [Chapter 12, Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/functions.html).

`id - 145` is a valid numeric expression. It evaluates to various (integer) numbers.
When it is used as `WHERE` condition, its value is converted to `boolean`.

The section [12.3.3 Logical Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html) says:

> MySQL evaluates any nonzero, non-`NULL` value to `TRUE`.

For all rows having `id != 145`, the expression `id - 145` is evaluated to a nonzero, non-`NULL` integer number that is treated as `TRUE` in logical context (in a `WHERE` condition f.e.)

To answer your question: yes, it is supposed to happen this way. It is not a MySQL bug, it is a bug in your query (or a typo if you like it more this way).

Comment: It was a typo. I meant to write `where id=145`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try `select * from mytable where 3;`

Basically any non-zero value will be equivalent to `true`.   This is also the case in many languages:  I first came across this behaviour in the `C` language many years ago, while puzzling at the marvel of

`while (*p++ = *q++);`  which is used to copy character strings.